# How to check that SEV is enabled for a Confidential Virtual Machine (VM) on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, confidential-vm-tag

I would like to create a Confidential VM on Google Cloud Platform (GCP) using the AMD SEV technology.
How do I check whether SEV *really* is enabled? I do not want to trust GCP, that is, I do not want to rely on the launch attestation report GCP provides.

Kind regards,
Alex

Comment: If Google's attestation is not acceptable, there is no solution. Compute Engine instances are virtualized, which means any test you attempt can also be virtualized.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/confidential-vm/docs/creating-cvm-instance#verify-sev) to see how to check SEV Enabled and to [view](https://cloud.google.com/compute/confidential-vm/docs/monitoring#view_launch_attestation_report_events) the launch attestation report .
To learn how to obtain more detailed information about the state of the Confidential VM instance by examining Cloud Monitoring integrity validation events, see [Validating Confidential VM instances using Cloud Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/compute/confidential-vm/docs/monitoring)

Edit 1:

Based on your comment suggested below :

check this [link](https://libvirt.org/kbase/launch_security_sev.html) if it might be useful

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly what I would like to avoid - trusting GCP ;-)

Comment: As far as I understand https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/7-ways-we-harden-our-kvm-hypervisor-at-google-cloud-security-in-plaintext, GCP does not support QEMU in the KVM context which is why the libvirt approach for Remote Attestation would not work.

Answer (score 0):

check in linux machine if its enabled:

```bash
dmesg | grep SEV | head
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.